# How can i add a input to the "valor2" ? - java

Tags: java, input

I just started to learn java, someone knows, how can i ask like "Type your values", and add id to the double[] valor2 ?

```
class test { // body start
    public static void main(String [] args) {
      
        double[] valor2 = {15, 4864, 4, 21}; // here is my doubt
     
        for (int a=0; a<valor2.length; a++){
            System.out.format("%s %d: O valor deste item é %10.2f %s%n", "Item", a+1, valor2[a], "reais");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add elements to an array. Use a `List<Double>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Scanner` for inputs.

```
public class TypeYours {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Double array to contain the values
        double[] values = new double[4];

        // The scanner take System.in (console input stream) as input.
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); /
        
        for (int a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a price:");

            // Store the scanned value
            values[a] = scanner.nextDouble();

            // Some %s is unnecessary so I removed them. 
            // Also, not %n but \n to start a new Line
            System.out.format("Item %d: O valor deste item é %10.2f reais\n", a + 1, values[a]);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that this is a very simple example: 1) The size of the `double[]` is hardcoded in the source as 4. If you want to dynamically change the `values`'s size, use `ArrayList<Double>` or some other instead. 2) `Scanner` can take `int`, `float`, `String` as well, try them in your coed. 3) `System.out.format` can be replaced by the combination of `System.out.print()` and `String.format(format, ...args)`, which is more flexible.